# Facebook Secure Content Warning and Images not displaying

Tags: facebook

I have a sandboxed FB App that I have been developing part time for over a year. About 2 weeks ago the application on start-up began to show the secure content warning:

ie.

(Firefox)
Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by a third party.

Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?

In IE I just get the following errors:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by http://xxxxx.com.au  /?fb_source=bookmark_apps&   ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=1_0
```

?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=1_0
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/ErrorPageTemplate.css 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/errorPageStrings.js 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/httpErrorPagesScripts.js 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/noConnect.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/bullet.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/down.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/favcenter.png 
    SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by res://ieframe.dll/background_gradient.jpg

I have tried this from a number of PC's so I amj sure the issue is not based on Browser setting. I have also tried setting up a new FB Application and point this at my old app but I still get the secure content warning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Baz

Answer (score 1):

Recently (actually it has been several months) facebook announced that all HTTP requests should be performed with encryption ('https') to make it safer. Although they are not blocking the content, they are screaming it out loud as "Please use https". I believe you can not disable the warnings, still browsing experience for the users will not be effected.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because when you are in an secure site (https) and has not safe content, some browsers don't load the unsafe content. The browse expect that all content is safe, any unsafe content may violate the security of the user.

The way you have to resolve this problem is putting your scripts and images in a https site.

Comment: Thanks. There was mixed content. I could see in the Firefox web console that the HTTP items were marked as 'mixed content'. What I couldn't understand is what had changed in the last month to make this  become an issue. Then I found that that my FB Settings had been modified to use 'secure browsing'. Not sure how but as soon as I changed it to unsercure browsing the FB resources were again HTTP. While in Sandbox mode I will leave it as HTTP and swing over to HTTPS before I release it.